# Adobe Flash ActionScript 3.0 ERROR 1009 When using UILoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I did a lot of search and can't find the answer, please kindly help me.
So I created one flash game called Snake Games and then another Flash which I use UILoader to load the snake game, however when I try to run that Flash game and check whether that flash will load the snake game, I encountered error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>
> at Main/addFood()
>
> at Main/init()
>
> at Main()

Here's the Main.as script inside the Snake Games
http://pastebin.com/raw/Z5ZBtLQn

Please kindly help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the source of null error is "Stage is unavailable". You need to alter your snake game constructor to first check stage, then call `init()` like this:

```
    public function Main(){
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    }
    function init(e:Event=null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        // rest of init() code
```